# How to display Hints on not active form

Tags: delphi

I wanna display hint just on mouse move, like in Winamp. No need to have focus on app. Thanks for help.

Comment: No can do with the built-in mechanism. VCL checks if the active window is from the current process or thread (depending on some EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint).

Comment: thanks for answer. Jus thought maybe there is a easy way for this, but i cant find info. I will pass with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the hint popup, but I'm not sure if you can do that if the application is not the focussed application.

This will show the hint for anything where the hint is set and ShowHint = True. But only if it is the focusseed Application. (As Sertac Akyuz said in a comment on the original post, VCL only does this for the currently active form).

```
procedure TForm1.ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  aPoint: TPoint;
  aControl: TControl;
begin

  aControl := TControl(Sender);
  if aControl.ShowHint = true then
  begin
    aPoint.X := X;
    aPoint.Y := Y;

    if Assigned(aControl.Parent) then
      aPoint := aControl.ClientToParent(aPoint);
    aPoint := ClientToScreen(aPoint);

    Application.ActivateHint(aPoint);
  end;
end;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can detect if mouse cursor position is over some controll by periodically checking mouse cursor position in relation of that controls client rectangle. You can do this using Timer and next code:

```
procedure TForm4.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
if Panel1.ClientRect.Contains(Panel1.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)) then
begin
    Form4.Caption := 'Panel1';
end
else if Panel2.ClientRect.Contains(Panel2.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)) then
begin
    Form4.Caption := 'Panel2';
end
else if Panel3.ClientRect.Contains(Panel3.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)) then
begin
    Form4.Caption := 'Panel3';
end
else if Panel4.ClientRect.Contains(Panel4.ScreenToClient(Mouse.CursorPos)) then
begin
    Form4.Caption := 'Panel4';
end
else Form4.Caption := 'None';
```

There is probably some better solution by iterating through your forms component list or even better creating your own specific list for this.
Now the only problem is that hint is shown only for active applications. So if you want for hints to be shown even when your application isn't active you will have to make your own hint system (Creating a small form with hint text shown).

Comment: Thanks. Wonder how winamp did this. Now i know why winamp can crash old DirectDRaw games sometimes on Windows 7

Comment: @user - Why wouldn't winamp do this? It's nothing strange. As I said in my comment to the question, it's the VCL that have not designed the hint system this way. You can modify it if you like so. Just remove `ForegroundTaskCheck` in `TApplication.ActivateHint`.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz hi again i copied vcl.forms.pas to new poject directory and removed ForegroundTaskCheck and works fine. But for older project i have many AV when using vcl.forms.pas, even not edited. Any suggestion why i cant use vcl.forms from source file? Im using Delphi XE7

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works now. I copied VCL.Forms.pas to project directory

removed there ForegroundTaskCheck like Sertac Akyuz said

```
var
  HintInfoMsg: TCMHintInfo;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  FHintActive := False;
  HintInfo.ReshowTimeout := 0;
  if FShowHint and (FHintControl <> nil) {and ForegroundTaskCheck(EnumAllWindowsOnActivateHint)} and
```

and most important thing is to add {$B-} in VCL.Forms.pas (without it many AV and crash)

```
unit Vcl.Forms;
{$B-}
```